# How do I enter file path in built-in open() function?

Tags: python, file-io, input

I have read the docs but it doesn't tell how we enter the file path in `open()` function.

If file path is:

```
/opt/myapp/report/sample.txt
```

or

`$MYPATH/report/sample.txt` (where $MYPATH=/opt/myapp)

Is it ok to write the statement this way:

```
f = open('/opt/myapp/report/sample.txt', "r")
```

or

```
f = open('$MYPATH/report/sample.txt', "r")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do here is expand the environment variables in the path, which can be done with [`os.path.expandvars()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

> Return the argument with environment variables expanded. Substrings of the form $name or ${name} are replaced by the value of
>   environment variable name. Malformed variable names and references to
>   non-existing variables are left unchanged.
>
> On Windows, %name% expansions are supported in addition to $name and ${name}.

E.g:

```
with open(os.path.expandvars(path), "r") as f:
    ...
```

Note my use of the `with` statement here, which is the best way to open files, as it ensures they are closed correctly, even when there is an exception, and reads nicely.

Comment: Thanks, and if there are no env variables, but plain path, like "/opt/myapp/report/sample.txt"?

Comment: @alwbtc Then the function will return the path unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.environ` to get the value of an environment variable, and `os.path.join` to combine it with the `report/sample.txt` part:

```
os.path.join(os.environ['MYPATH'], 'report/sample.txt')
```

The absolute path will also work.

Comment: OK, how do I put it in open() function?